# update query working in shell but not in nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**this query is working in mongo shell**

```
db.orders.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111"),
"submittedTo":ObjectId("5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2") },
{ $set: {
    ... "vendorOrder" : [
    ...                 {
    ...                         "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95113"),
    ...                         "publicationCode" : "TOI",
    ...                         "publicationName" : "Times of India",
    ...                         "editionName" : "chennai city",
    ...                         "productCode" : "TCE1",
    ...                         "subscriptionCopies" : 70,
    ...                         "tradeCopies" : 9
    ...                 },
    ...                 {
    ...                         "_id" : ObjectId("5e26be38c13b7149d0a95112"),
    ...                         "publicationCode" : "ET",
    ...                         "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
    ...                         "editionName" : "chennai city",
    ...                         "productCode" : "ECE1",
    ...                         "subscriptionCopies" : 20,
    ...                         "tradeCopies" : 4
    ...                 }
    ...         ]}})
```

**Mongo shell response:** `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }`

but its **not working in nodejs**:here is what i have tried so far
**query1:**

```
exports.editOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { orderId, dealerId, vendorOrder } = req.body;
try {
    const orders = await Order.updateOne(
      {
        _id: orderId,
        submittedTo:dealerId
      },
      { $set: { vendorOrder } }
    );
 res.status(200).json({
      orders,
      message: "order submitted"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};
```

**query2**

```
exports.editOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { orderId, dealerId, vendorOrder } = req.body;

  try {
    const orders = await Order.updateOne(
      {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderId),
        submittedTo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(dealerId)
      },
      { $set: { vendorOrder: vendorOrder } }
    );
 res.status(200).json({
      orders,
      message: "order submitted"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};
```

**query 3**: **with double "" rest code is exactly the same**

```
const { orderId, dealerId, vendorOrder } = req.body;

      try {
        const orders = await Order.updateOne(
          {
            "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderId),
            "submittedTo": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(dealerId)
          },
          { $set: { "vendorOrder": vendorOrder } }
        );
```

**POSTMAN JSON:**

```
{
    "orderId":"5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111",
    "submittedTo":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2",
    "vendorOrder" : [
                {
                   "_id" : "5e26be38c13b7149d0a95113",
                   "publicationCode" : "TOI",
                   "publicationName" : "Times of India",
                   "editionName" : "chennai city",
                   "productCode" : "TCE1",
                   "subscriptionCopies" : 70,
                   "tradeCopies" : 90
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "5e26be38c13b7149d0a95112",
                    "publicationCode" : "ET",
                    "publicationName" : "Economic Times",
                    "editionName" : "chennai city",
                    "productCode" : "ECE1",
                    "subscriptionCopies" : 20,
                    "tradeCopies" : 40
                }
        ]
```

**POSTMAN RESPONSE**

```
{
    "orders": {
        "n": 0,
        "nModified": 0,
        "ok": 1
    },
    "message": "order submitted"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two remarks:

Query #2 (or #3) is correct - you should always cast strings to `ObjectId` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(...)` since both fields are stored as string in your database.

The next issue with your code is that your destructuring:

`const { orderId, dealerId, vendorOrder } = req.body;`

expects `dealerId` while your payload contains `submittedTo` field, so you should try:

```
const { orderId, submittedTo, vendorOrder } = req.body;

const orders = await Order.updateOne(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(orderId),
        submittedTo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(submittedTo)
    },
    { $set: { vendorOrder: vendorOrder } }
);
```

which works fine (keeping in mind that `nModified` will be returned as `0` if there are no changes between `vendorOrder` variable and `vendorOrder` being stored in your database.

Comment: thanks @ mickl but even after editing postman payload it still giving the same response though i have changed the payload  {
    "orderId":"5e26be38c13b7149d0a95111",
    "submittedTo":"5e2555363405363bc4bf86c2" rest payload is same except changes in the tradecopies inside vendorOrder

Comment: @sachin I tried and it works. Can you paste your `Order` schema ?

Comment: const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    vendorOrder: [
      {
        publicationCode: {
          type: String
        },
        publicationName: {
          type: String
        },
        editionName: {
          type: String
        },
        productCode: {
          type: String
        },
        subscriptionCopies: {
          type: Number
        },
        tradeCopies: {
          type: Number
        }
      }
    ],
submittedTo: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }, @mickl

Comment: @sachin looks fine. Here's my working example: https://pastebin.com/532U8zMX , please make sure that the database you're connected to already contains the collection and the document you're trying to modify (collection name should be `orders`)

Comment: i dont know whats the issue with my code, i am stuck in this, the same document with same id's is there in db i have modified it with the same query in mongoshell also the ids are same in the asked question

Comment: @sachin you can add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to see whether mongoose command is executed on the same collection you are running your command from mongo shell